# Why won't scala bind my string for pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've posted the full code here but you can probably do with just the lines I've indicated:

```
  rawModifiers.map(_.trim()).map {
    case str: String if str.startsWith("--") ⇒

      val substring = str.substring(2)
      val space = substring.indexOf(' ')

      (substring, space) match {        <------ nothing is bound yet here

          //This is where I have the problem. i gets set!!!

          case m@(full: String, i) if i > 0 ⇒ Seq(new ValModifier(full.take(i), full.substring(i)))
          case m@(part: String, _) ⇒ Seq(new FlagModifier(part))

      }
    case str: String if str.startsWith("-") ⇒

      val substring = str.substring(1)
      val space = substring.indexOf(' ')

      (substring, space) match {

          case m@(v: String, i) if i > 0 && v.length == 1 ⇒ Seq(new ValModifier(v.take(i), v.substring(i)))
          case m@(v: String, i) if i > 0 && v.length > 1  ⇒ throw new IllegalArgumentException()
          case m@(v: String, _) if v.length >= 1 ⇒ MultiFlagModifier(v)
          case _ ⇒ throw new IllegalArgumentException()
      }
    case _ ⇒ throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  } flatMap(x ⇒ x)
```

I've tried about five variants of this, using `m@` and not using `m@`, originally using a `Some(...)` to wrap the `String` so I could treat it not as a `char` array, etc. Same result - **no matter what, the variables `full` and `part` are `null`!)**.

The same thing happens below with `v`.

Disregard this statement:
<strike>Assigning the variable `val combo = (tuple)` works if I then match on that, but *why*?</strike>

Strangely, in both cases, the integer `i` does get set. So something odd is happening but I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Dunno, but `indexOf(' ')\n(substring, space) match {` is hard to parse visually & actually. Tuple and arg list look the same. I'd add a blank line.

Comment: Done, you are right. I ended up working around it with something I'll post but it is odd that this was happening

Comment: If you could reduce this to a *minimal* example that shows the problem, that would be helpful.

Comment: It does not seem possible that only a fraction of a piece matches. It should match completely or not at all. Where do you get a value for `i`?